# How set up borders of UITextField?

Tags: ios6, uitextfield, border

I have a big UITextField with opaque borders. And when I writing a lot, my text comes behind the border and don't transfer. How can I set borders and transfers?

Thank you a lot for help.

Comment: What do you mean the text does not transfer?

Comment: @verbumdei If I write a lot of text It comes only right and don't transfer on the next line.

Comment: Could you try UITextView instead?